# What is causing my input to not be saved into my django model database?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a quiz website using Django. I have created a modelform in which input boxes appear on the website alongside a submit button. Inputting text into it and submitting it works just fine and sends a POST request aswell, according to cmd. However, it doesn't seem to save the inputs into the model, which is what i am trying to achieve.

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .models import Question, InputText
from .forms import AnswerForm

# Only shows relevant view

def kvizpost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnswerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            text = form.cleaned_data()
            text.save()
            return redirect('kviz:kviz')

    else:
        form = AnswerForm()
    return render(request, 'vprasanja/kviz.html', {'form' : form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from kvizapp.models import InputText

class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InputText
        fields = ('vnesi',)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Only shows relevant model

class InputText(models.Model):
    vnesi = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

kviz.html

```
{% block body %}
<form action = "/kviz/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Vnos">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT:** I was requested to show the URLs.

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<kviz/', views.kviz, name='kviz'), # The kviz view just renders the page.
]
```

Comment: Is the form action of "/kviz/" pointing to that `kvizpost` view? Try with just `action=""`. And show the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect('kviz:kviz')
else:
    # if form is not valid
    return render(request, 'vprasanja/kviz.html', {'form' : form})
```

Save the form using **save()** method on form instance, since you are using **ModelForm** everything should work fine .

Refer : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: Apologies for not sharing this information earlier. But, directly saving the ModelForm does not appear to change anything. Same result.